# Dockerizing MERN APP for Production - Only See: "Welcome to NGINX!"

Tags: docker, nginx, dockerfile, mern, nginx-config

I am completely new to Docker & NGINX so I'm essentially learning as I go. I'm trying to get my Dockerized MERN app setup for production (not a critical app, just for my learning purposes), and after reading countless tutorials I've gotten so far as getting my app only for a Dev environment. However as the title suggests, I want to get this working for a prod-type environment (thinking of hosting in AWS), so I need to optimize it a bit more.

I'll show you my Dockerfile.prod for the Frontend:

```
FROM node:18-alpine AS build
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build


FROM nginx
# Copy build assets from build/ folder & place them in nginx/html
COPY --from=build /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
```

My production NGINX configuration file:

```
upstream client { 
    server client:3000;
}
upstream api {
    server api:3001;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    
    location / { 
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
    
    location /sockjs-node {
        proxy_pass http://client;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        # setting 'Upgrade' allows a tunnel setup between client & proxied server http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/websocket.html
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
    }

    location /api {
        proxy_pass http://api;
    }
}
```

My Dockerfile.prod for NGINX

```
FROM nginx
COPY ./prod.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

Lastly, my docker-compose.prod.yml file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  nginx:
    depends_on:
      - api
      - client
    restart: always
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.prod
      context: ./nginx
    ports:
      - "3000:80"
  api:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: ./backend
    volumes:
      - '/app/node_modules'
      - './backend:/app'
    command: npm start
  client:
    build: 
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.prod
      context: ./frontend
    volumes:
      - '/app/node_modules'
      - './frontend:/app'
    environment:
      - WDS_SOCKET_PORT=0
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
```

From my understanding, the NGINX container is built first using its Dockerfile.prod, thus overriding its default.conf file with the prod.conf I made. Then upon the build of the 'client' container (my frontend) & the execution of its respective Dockerfile.prod, the build contents will be copied over to that NGINX's html folder. So technically, that 'Welcome to NGINX' screen should've been overridden right?

However when inspecting the location where I copied my build contents, that doesn't seem to be the case (see [NGINX Image /usr/share/nginx/html contents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPnFR.png)). For what its worth, the client container seems to be built before the NGINX container does, at least from the order I see the logs being printed out (see [Docker Compose Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNZb2.png)). Regardless, it seems like I'm doing something wrong, and my only hunch is that the NGINX portion of the Frontend's Dockerfile.prod is overriden by the execution of the NGINX's Dockerfile.prod. Can anyone please help me? I'm just beyond confused at this point.

Directory Structure:

```
.
├── frontend
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   ├── Dockerfile.prod
│   ├── babel.config.json
│   ├── nginx
│   │   └── default.conf
├── nginx
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   ├── Dockerfile.prod
│   ├── default.conf
│   └── prod.conf
├── docker-compose.prod.yml
├── docker-compose.yml
```

[Docker Compose Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNZb2.png)

[NGINX Image /usr/share/nginx/html contents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPnFR.png)

Comment: You misunderstand the last 4 lines of your Dockerfile.prod, you cant just copy the files from the one image to another. With those lines your frontend is just an nginx image with those files at the copied location. In the end you have 2 nginx images. One with the built data from npm and the other one with the config file. It would be recommended to have 1 service per image, so you just have a running instance of your frontend and use the nginx as proxy.

Comment: Thanks @Geilmaker, I see what you mean. So should I just remove the nginx definition from my docker-compose.prod.yml & just rely on the frontend Dockerfile.prod image to create the nginx as proxy? I do have an nginx/default.conf within the frontend folder. Perhaps I can set it up in there?

Comment: Okay, sorry, my last comment, that I just deleted, was simply wrong. I guess I have an idea how this is going, maybe we have a walkthrough together, I'll write it inside an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start with serving the react app for production, I would recommend the following tutorial on this: https://dev.to/thexdev/dockerize-production-reactjs-3ai9

So you might want to have the following `Dockerfile.prod`:

```
FROM node:18-alpine AS build
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

FROM nginx:stable
EXPOSE 80
COPY ./your/path/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf # That file needs to be created, you can adjust the first path to yours
COPY --from=build /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html  # Please have a look if its /app/dist or /app/build
```

The `default.conf` file you need to create should look like the following:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```

I would also recommend creating a `.dockerignore` file in the same directory where your Dockerfile lives with the following content:

```
node_modules
```

That way you don't copy that folder into the image - it's created itself by the `npm i` command.

With that done you should have a production react app.

Then you should edit your `docker-compose.prod.yml`:

```
version: '3'
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:stable
    container_name: nginx
    depends_on:
      - api
      - client
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./sites-enabled:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    ports:
      - "3000:80"
  api:
    container_name: api
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: ./backend
    volumes:
      - '/app/node_modules'
      - './backend:/app'
    command: npm start
    expose:
      - 3001
  client:
    container_name: client
    build: 
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.prod
      context: ./frontend
    expose:
      - 80
```

That way you have an nginx instance, that should work as a proxy and route your requests to the api or client container.

For that to work you need to create the `sites-enabled` directory where your `docker-compose.prod.yml` file lives (so it gets mounted as volume inside the nginx container). Inside that folder you need to create a `<anyname>.conf` file with the following content:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://client:80;
    }

    location /api/ {
        proxy_pass http://api:3001$request_uri;
    }
}
```

That would be a production setup. You have one image for each service and an nginx container, that is receiving the requests and route them to the corresponding service. You shouldn't use the nginx instance inside your client container to also route requests to the api container, that would be bad practice. The nginx in your client image is only for making this container a standalone, it should not interact externally.

Comment: Dude yes! Based on your original comment, I made some changes as you mentioned here, and it's working fine! I want to mention that I removed the 'nginx' portion from the docker-compose.prod.yml to then solely rely on the nginx proxy that's created in the Dockerfile.prod for the frontend. I'll give some additional details in a new post. Thanks again @Geilmaker!

Comment: I edited my answer for completeness. That should be a full production setup - also including the api container. In theory you should be able to access the client on `/sockjs-node/` and the api on `/api/`. On `/` nothing should be served currently. Maybe have a look if that full setup is still working or needs adjustments. Or you stay with your self-found setup, even tho you should read my last abstract about good practice and service splitting. If anything is not working dont hesitate to write a comment :)

Comment: Thanks for this further clarification, I did feel uneasy with nginx not having its own container, but I thought thats just the way things would work for a production env. But I do have a few questions. 1) How does the nginx container from the docker-compose get the contents from the nginx instance inside my client container? - Expose 80 in the client Dockerfile? (2) How do I create sites-enabled? Is it just implicitly created in docker-compose?  Thanks again!

Comment: In a production setup you should definetly have a seperated nginx as proxy in front of your containers. 1) Right, your frontend container works on its own, if you access it on port 80 its serving your application. Requesting the nginx proxy just redirects the request to the container on the port. Thats possible due to the export: 80 inside the docker-compose. 2) It's just a folder. That way you can use the original nginx image and just mount a volume inside, like declared in the compose file. So you can insert that file into the container and use it there.

Comment: I see, my only problem right now is that I get the following error: 2023/07/26 18:48:13 [error] 20#20: *1 "/etc/nginx/html/index.html" is not found (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.24.0.1, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:3000" . However I do see that the contents from 'sites-enabled' is inside 'etc/nginx/conf.d'. In that respective file (sites-enabled/prod.conf), I did comment out the 'location / '.

Comment: Ya I could thought about something might be wrong. Sorry for that. Which address did you access?

Comment: No problem dude, I really appreciate your help :)  I tried accessing localhost:3000.

Comment: Can you try access http://localhost:3000/api/ and http://localhost:3000/sockjs-node/ and have a look what gets served there?

Comment: Unfortunately both don't work :/

Comment: Could you try the minimal setup from above? Just override the file and restart the docker container.

Comment: Yah do you mean within the sides-enabled/prod.conf or frontend/nginx/default.conf?

Comment: The `prod.conf` file - afterwards try accessing http://localhost:3000/ - if its not working maybe execute `ping client` inside the nginx docker container (docker exec -it nginx bash) - then type it in.

Comment: Ok I can see the frontend :) . Unfortunately the api is not working :/ . I suppose I can just re-add the stuff I took out.

Comment: So the api works on Postman now that I re-added 'location /api', 'upstream api', & 'location /sockjs-node'. However when trying to access these endpoints via the frontend, they don't return anything.

Comment: I updated the answer. Guess this one should work.

Comment: Yes, thats a development problem. In our case you want to setup a production environment - such an environment wouldn't use `localhost` - instead some domain. I think you want to access the api from your frontend container with a url including localhost (like localhost:3001/xxx). The problem is, that this is now served in another docker container. So you have to use some other hostname (like the IP of your computer) to access it or use api:3001 -> somehow the routing needs to find the other docker container. In production you would use example.com/api and dns would do the job.

Comment: Thanks @Geilmaker! I got it working, looks like I forgot the last "/" in "location /api/".  I omitted the  ":3001$request_uri;" at the end of "proxy pass http..", and it's working. Now the next steps are to try getting this inside a CI/CD pipeline & host it. Thanks again for all your help man, wouldn't gotten this far without it

Comment: Glad to hear it! Good look with the coming steps! If you need related help just drop it here (or a link to a new question).

Answer (score 0):

I want to preface that @Geilmaker's answer is the correct answer. However I also want to give additional details in case anyone has a similar setup.

The main issue was as Geilmaker pointed out, that I essentially had two nginx images (one containing the build contents for the React portion). The first created during the Dockerfile.prod for the Frontend & the other created during the docker-compose.prod.yml execution:

```
 nginx:
   depends_on:
     - api
     - client
   restart: always
   build:
     dockerfile: Dockerfile.prod
     context: ./nginx
   ports:
     - "3000:80"
```

But I didn't expose the nginx image with build contents. Rather, I exposed the one with just its default configuration. Furthermore, since the Dockerfile.prod for the Frontend only ran 'npm run build', the React app was not being served & prod.conf was configured to just default to its index.html for any default location - which at this point is only the welcome page.

So what I had to do was to rely on the nginx proxy created for Dockerfile.prod for the Frontend & add some of the configuration used for the prod.conf into the default.conf that resides within the Frontend folder (for example the proxying for the Express api).

The result looking like:

frontend/Dockerfile.prod

```
FROM node:18-alpine AS build
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build


FROM nginx
# Copy build assets from build/ folder & place them in nginx/html
COPY --from=build /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY ./nginx/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
EXPOSE 80
```

frontend/nginx/default.conf

```
upstream client { 
    server client:3000;
}
upstream api {
    server api:3001;
}

server {

    listen 80;
    
    location / { 
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        index index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location /sockjs-node {
        proxy_pass http://client;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        # setting 'Upgrade' allows a tunnel setup between client & proxied server http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/websocket.html
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
    }

    location /api {
        proxy_pass http://api;
    }
}
```

And docker-compose.prod.yml looking like:

```
version: '3'
services:
  api:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: ./backend
    volumes:
      - '/app/node_modules'
      - './backend:/app'
    command: npm start
  client:
    build: 
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.prod
      context: ./frontend
    volumes:
      - '/app/node_modules'
      - './frontend:/app'
    environment:
      - WDS_SOCKET_PORT=0
    ports:
      - '3000:80'
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
```

Notice the removal of the 'nginx' definition & the port-mapping occuring within the 'client' definition.

Upon executing

> docker-compose -f docker-compose.prod.yml up

I can finally see my React application. Thanks @Geilmaker again